# Mysql Query group by

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I am trying to make a query to get some results:

I have a table with some data:

```
client | price

1 | 100

1 | 150

1 | 200

2 | 90

2 | 130

2 | 200

3 | 95

3 | 120

3 | 250
```

I would like with one query to select the results and order it by price and client and get them in this form, ordered by the best price of each clint:

```
2 | 90

2 | 130

2 | 200

3 | 95

3 | 120

3 | 250

1 | 100

1 | 150

1 | 200
```

Comment: What should happen if two clients are ties on their lowest price, but not on their second lowest? Can they be returned in either order, or should the second lowest price be used as a tie-breaker?

Comment: Mark, second comment read, thank you for that remark. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @Alexander: The second comment is the first comment now :). I decided to delete my first comment as I am no longer interested in knowing the answer. If I know the answer to the second question that's enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl.client, ytbl.price
FROM (SELECT client, min(price) as mpr FROM yourtable group by client) tbl
JOIN yourtable ytbl ON ytbl.client=tbl.client
ORDER BY tbl.mpr ASC, tbl.client ASC, ytbl.price ASC
```

Something like that...

Comment: Hi Alexander, it works great!

Thank you very much :-)

Cheers
Nik

Comment: Great to hear that!
I see that you're new here. If you find the answer to your question, mark it as the correct answer. When you accept an answer you get points, so does the person who gives the correct answer. It's what keeps this forum going (besides altruism).